# Typos have been authorized

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the meaning and use of above sentence if somebody replied through their mobile device and wrote below sentence in the lower part of email

> Sent from my mobile device. Typos have been authorized.

What is his/her intended meaning here?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the writer is basically saying:

> I typed this from a mobile device. Therefore, I didn't have access to a full keyboard, or a spell-checker. Instead, I typed it on a small screen using only my thumbs, so don't be surprised if you find a typo.

It's meant to be a humorous and concise way to alert the reader that there may be typos.

My guess is that the writer spends more time proofreading emails sent from a desktop or laptop computer than when using a cell phone to respond to emails, or that the person isn't an experienced texter, and has noticed that they are more prone to make typos  when sending a text message. Rather than being embarrassed or frustrated by these typos, or spending a lot of time correcting them, this line gets appended to their messages instead.

I would guess that the writer has this as part of a regular "signature" in their mobile device, and that it shows up at the end of many if not all of the messages sent from their phone.

Usually, *authorization* comes from a higher authority, like a boss, or a corporate decision. In this case, the person is "authorizing" typos because he or she has made the conscientious decision to not worry about them if they happen, as if to say, *"What do you expect? I'm typing this on a tiny screen, for crying out loud!"*

I found it clever and I literally LOL'ed when I read your question.

Answer (score 1):

“Typos have been authorized” is not common or well-known, and as far as I know it has no single, well-understood meaning.  Thus, to find out the sender's intended meaning of the phrase, you will need to ask him or her.  What we can address here are *possible* meanings.

(a) One of the simplest interpretations: "I take responsibility for any typos in this message".  That is, the sender acknowledges the message may contain typos, and (probably for the sake of expediency) is not going to root them all out.

(b) A variant of the above: "There may be typos in this message.  I don't care".   Again, the sender acknowledges the message may contain typos, but because it is so tedious to fix them using the mobile device, will do nothing about them.

(c) The sender had another person glance at the message (or had a spell-check or grammar check program test it) and the person or program approved sending the message as is.  In this interpretation, *[authorized](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/authorized#Adjective)* is used with its dictionary meaning,  “Explicitly allowed”, and the agent who has allowed the typos is another person or a program, *vs* the sender, who did the allowing in the other two interpretations.